# Bash: recursively find php files, preprocess with php, capture output to html files

Tags: php, html, bash

I'm looking to scan a directory for files named *.php, and then execute each one with the PHP preprocessor, and capture the output to the same location as the file, with the same filename, only .html extension instead of .php.

so far I have:

```
find . -type f -name "*.php" | xargs -I {} php {} >> '{ dirname {}; basename {} .php; }'
```

thanks for your help on this bash puzzle !

Comment: Why not do it with PHP itself instead of Bash?

Comment: imho its what bash does best.  Then again the beer tastes the same if you open it with a bottle opener or a hammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this works...

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/var/www/*.php
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Running script $f..."
  php $f > $f.out
done
```

Maybe needing full path to bin where your php lives.

**EDIT:**

```
php $f > ${f%.php}.html
```

Comment: it'll be doing `php whatever.php > whatever.php.out`. need to strip off the extension for the .out part.

Comment: True.  But doesn't bother me or `cat`.  But now I do see the OP wants name.html

Comment: yes, I'm aiming for the extension .html INSTEAD of .php, preserving directory structure to output folder.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off with using `-exec` directly in `find`. xargs is for when you need to pass bulk parameters, while you're looking for something that's more per-file. e.g.

```
find ... -exec "php {} > $(basename {}).html;"
```

or something similar. Been a while since I've had to use bash, so that almost certainly won't work, but should get you started.